How to Render Custom UI on a 3.5 Inch Touch Display with Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi
I'm currently working on a project that involves a Raspberry Pi equipped with a 3.5 inch touch display. My goal is to create a user interface (UI) specifically for file selection tasks. I've opted for Ubuntu Server as the operating system because I plan to integrate ROS2 for other aspects of my project.
My question is: Is it possible to design a custom window for this UI and successfully render it on a 3.5 inch touch display that's connected to a Raspberry Pi? If so, what tools or libraries would you recommend for creating such a UI? Additionally, are there any considerations or limitations I should be aware of when designing for a small touch display?
Any insights o
